# Postfix Pipe then forward to original recipient

Tags: postfix, pipe

I may well be on the wrong track here with what I'm trying to do, so I'd appreciate any advice.

Is it possible to pipe email to a script (which I have working), and then have Postfix forward it on to its original recipient using transport_maps, virtual_alias_maps or some other Postfix type thing?

Looking at the Postfix mailflow diagram, the answer is probably no because Pipe does not then go on to re-queue the message. Therefore my question is, if not, then what is the best way of doing what I am trying to do? Should my piped script (which basically dumps the email content to a text file) also be in charge of sending this on using something like sendmail? Or is there a better way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use feature [always_bcc](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc). Add this parameter in **main.cf**.

```
always_bcc = mypipe@example.com
```

Then you can put mypipe@example.com to the alias file e.g `/etc/aliases`

```
mypipe: "|/path/to/myscript.sh"
```

Don't forget to postalias the alias file.

**Note**: domain example.com should be a [local domains](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#wtf), because pipe must be in local classes domain

**UPDATE**

If your case is sender-dependent script or recipient-dependent script, you can use the variations of `always_bcc`, they are `recipient_bcc_maps` for recipient-dependent script or `sender_bcc_maps` for sender-dependent script

Comment: That's an interesting idea. It would work great if I always wanted to bcc to a particular address, but my aim is to have various email accounts each using a different piped script (again, working), and then have them forwarded to the original recipients. Any further ideas?

Comment: That sounds more like it. Just left work but can't wait to get home and give it a try. Sorry I can't increase your answer rating as a new user :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, it worked a treat. I still had to mess about with transport and virtual a bit because the recipient to BCC had it's mailbox on another (Exchange) server, which I didn't specify. I'm amazed more and more each day by what Postfix can do, and I get the feeling I've only just scratched the surface. Thanks again!