# postfix - hock - extracting information out of processed emails

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, exim

### The setup

Linux, Debian Wheezy, serves as mail server for about 1000 users. Courier and Postfix installed in this box.

#### Info about the server

It is a postfix setup which drops the emails to the mailboxes under`/home/vmail/$domain/$user` - this part is working.

#### What I plan to do:

I would like to implement that when an email gets sent via the server a script (`/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh`) gets triggered so that I can log and take actions. 
Why? I would like to implement a slowdown/disable action on an account if such an account gets hacked and someone starts sending spam emails over the system.

Right now I am rotating the logfiles and extracting which user sent how many emails over a period of time and than lock down the account if they are sending more than x emails per hour (configurable). This log-rotate implementation is not nice, so I thought it might be good to have a hock which gets triggered every time an email gets sent via smtps (right now just smtps is allowed for users - no smtp).

I have found [this manual](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail) and it gave me some ideas how to implement "hocks" for the different delivery methods (smtp, smtpd, pickup)

In main.cf I have added the following lines

```
hooksmtp   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=F user=vmail argv=/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh ${sender} ${size} ${recipient} smtp
hooksmtps  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=F user=vmail argv=/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh ${sender} ${size} ${recipient} smtps
hookpickup unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=F user=vmail argv=/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh ${sender} ${size} ${recipient} pickup`
```

and altered the following lines also in main.cf

```
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=hooksmtp:dummy
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=hooksmtps:dummy  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes  -o smt
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup -o content_filter=hookpickup:dummy
```

to call the hocks on the specific actions.

Right now the triggered script looks like this and I will improve it later .....

```
cat /home/vmail/mail_logger.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S) $@ >> /home/vmail/mail_logger.log
```

I have now the problem, that now all the email gets handled by the "hooks" (which is good) but do not get delivered to the original destination (which is bad).

I had a look at the postfix manual and figured out that I could implement that for all emails a bcc is sent to an local email than get processed, but I thought that there should be another method of handling this.

**So the question is** how to change these lines that the "hocks" gets notified and the mails still get processed like they were before without the need to do a BCC and than process that BCC.

Other ideas of handling the problem above are also welcome. But please note that I don't want to run the spam scanner on that box because spam scanning gets handled by 4 MX nodes in front of the server (running debian and sa-exim).

**Update 1: My first findings following the comments are**

I have followed the comments and made these changes

in main.cf I have added the following lines

```
local_transport = hookpickup
always_bcc = extract@localhost
```

in master.cf I made sure that the hookpickup is in place

```
hookpickup unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=F user=vmail
    argv=/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh ${sender} ${size} ${recipient} pickup
```

I did some tests and figured out, that

- If I send a mail via SMTP, a BCC gets sent to extract@localhost and the "hook" picks it up and the script processes the content. - GOOD
- If I send a email locally to root, the "hook" picks it up and the script processed the content but the email does not reach its destination - BAD.

I need now to setup that the 
    local_transport = hookpickup
just gets "triggered" if the email comes from the mailbox extract@localhost

**Update 2: My next findings following the answer are**

I have followed the first answer and made these changes

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/map_mytransport
always_bcc = extract@localhost
# removed: local_transport = hookpickup
```

The file /etc/postfix/map_mytransport has the content

```
extract@localhost hookpickup:
```

Every time that you alter the content of /etc/postfix/map_mytransport you have to run `postmap /etc/postfix/map_mytransport` which will generate the file /etc/postfix/map_mytransport.db which postfix actually uses.

Please make sure that you have `transport_maps` not defined before or you will overwrite it with this setting and you could cause unexpected behavior. I followed to 70% [this manual](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy) 
setting up the server and have not had it set but I know that other people have.

In master.cf I altered the hookpickup and added more values for debugging

```
hookpickup unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe  flags=F user=vmail
    argv=/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh client_address=${client_address} client_hostname=${client_hostname} client_port=${client_port} client_protocol=${client_protocol} domain=${domain} extension=${extension}mailbox=${mailbox} nexthop=${nexthop} original_recipient=${original_recipient} recipient=${recipient} sasl_method=${sasl_method}  sasl_sender=${sasl_sender} sasl_username=${sasl_username} sender=${sender} size=${size}
```

The full description of the parameters can be found [here](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html).

To get the solution working I added the user extract to the system and restarted postfix.

The script `/home/vmail/mail_logger.sh` is now getting in "real time" the info's that I need to lock down an account if it sends out to many emails (defined per an threshold configured in the database).

Comment: `I could implement that for all emails a bcc is sent to an local email than get processed, but I thought that there should be another method of handling this` --> What's wrong with this method? Have you tried it?

Comment: End clients could consider this as that I am coping their emails.... Additionally I would have to make sure that just emails to that specific local email (extract@localhost) gets forwarded to the hock and not every email (like root@localhost). If this is the only option that I have, I am happy to read your hints and I will put my final version online here...

Comment: One of BCC method has been asked in [this question](http://serverfault.com/a/593684/218590). It has downside tough, you can differentiate email between pickup, smtps, and smtp. And for `content_filter` method like above, you should resubmit again to postfix. See [this documentation page](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter) for sample script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding `local_transport` with your *hookpickup*, you can setup `transport_maps`.

```
#main.cf
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/mytransport

#/etc/postfix/mytransport
extract@localhost hookpickup:
```

In this mode, just email send out to extract@localhost will be delivered to hookpickup